# Problem with Android Launcher clicking buttons

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

Let me start by saying that I am very new to this so apologies in advance.

I need to create a very basic launcher, for a specific use case for limited numbers of users. I have created the basics of the app and it's actually working well for what it needs to do. The problem I have is this:

When running in the emulator, it seems to work ok, but when I run it on the device, no button clicks are working the first time I tap the screen. I originally thought this was down to the focusable issues or nested onClickListeners that I've seen mentioned elsewhere, but I realised that it doesn't seem to be the case.

What's happening is that when any activity loads, I have to touch anywhere on the screen first, then any button will work on the first click. As soon as I go to a new activity, this behaviour is the same on that activity, and then when going back to the main activity, this behaviour is there again. So as long as I tap anywhere on the screen first, then clicking on a button will work first time.

I am pulling my hair out being a newbie to this, but it's all that's preventing me getting this app into testing really.

Can anyone help?

Here's the xml snippet for the main activity for the buttons

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="93dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/phoneButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ph"

            />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cpButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cp"
                />
```

Here's the Java for this activity including one example of button handling

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        initialiseButtonsMain();
    }


        private void initialiseButtonsMain () {
            findViewById(R.id.phoneButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent navIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.szchoiceway.btsuite");
                    if (navIntent != null) {
                        startActivity(navIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found

                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: does it work if you get rid of all the uioptions? It seems from your description that the previous activity doesn't finish it's lifecycle until you interact with the phone.
Try putting this line ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);``` after  the ```decorview``` line

Comment: @DJ.Aduvanchik Hello, thanks for pointing me in this direction. The code you mentioned didn't work, but removing all the uioptions code did work! So I see where the issue is but still don't know how to fix it! The use of that code was to make the app fullscreen all the time, no nav bar, status bar or action bar

Comment: that's a good step. try juggling where ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)``` goes. it seems the view is not in the foreground until you interact with it. Check the lifecycle of the activity, maybe the other activity lifecycle does not complete. It could also be the null pointer of the Intent since if's null, it will not work properly

Comment: @DJ.Aduvanchik I've moved it around to various places and it either makes no difference or causes and app crash on start. Not sure how to check the lifecycle of the activity?

Comment: ok I got it working but removing all the `decorView` code. The outcome appears to be the same, there is no code to hide the navigation bar but the navigation bar doesn't appear on my device anyway, maybe the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` covers making this happen?

Comment: The top Nav bar still pops up for a half second when laughing that activity though...

Comment: try to change the app theme in the styles folder to ```<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">```

Comment: Do you mean in the styles.xml? I don't have a styles folder. In the XML I have `<style name="Widget.Theme.Audi.ActionBar.Fullscreen" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Theme.Audi.ButtonBar.Fullscreen" parent="">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    </style>`

Comment: yes, ```styles.xml```. you can change the parent to NoActionBar in the first line, you will have to sure to search for the right one for you, since it gets updated sometimes